# iFrame is not saving session with Laravel in Chrome and Safari

Tags: php, laravel, session, iframe

I am loading a Laravel application through an iFrame. The Session is started with Laravel's StartSession middleware (placed in `app/Http/Kernel.php`):

```
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
];
```

In the application I save my session variables like so:

```
Session::put('mode', true);
Session::save();
```

They are getting saved if I access my application directly and also on the website in which I have embeded the iFrame but only in **Firefox**.

In **Chrome and Safari** the Session is not saved.

Maybe there are missing headers which cause that problem?

Comment: is this problem resolved?? can i have same problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue working with shopify apps.
So the solution is:

- In config / session file - option 'same_site' should be 'none'
- In config / session file - option 'secure' should be 'true'

Part of this solution was taken from here - [Here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/csrf-cookie-in-iframe-on-other-domain-chrome-blocking-third-party-cookies?page=1)